# Is there a tool for putting together multiple SVGs onto one co-ordinate canvas?

Tags: canvas, svg

new coder here so please go easy on me. I've found an online map called JQV map that uses SVG paths to plot out the country shapes. I've also found another free license collection of much more detailed SVG plots of individual countries. Each country is on its own 'canvas' (don't know if that is the right word for it) so if I put them together they would just overlay. I was wondering how can I sew together these countries and recreate the map with my new country shapes?

Also will the requirement of many more vector paths make the page much slower to load?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll take this question to Quora.